# Select rows based on values in various columns in R

Tags: r, row, subset

Three columns of my `data.frame` contain subjects. I want to subset this `data.frame` for different subjects. E.g. if I want to have a `data.frame` with the subject "apple", the row should be selected if the word "apple" appears in one of the three columns.

```
doc    <- c("blabla1", "blabla2", "blabla3", "blabla4")
subj.1 <- c("apple", "prune", "coconut", "berry")
subj.2 <- c("coconut", "apple", "cherry", "banana and prune")
subj.3 <- c("berry", "banana", "apple and berry", "pear", "prune")
subjects <- c("apple", "prune", "coconut", "berry", "cherry", "pear", "banana")

mydf <- data.frame(doc, subj.1, subj.2, subj.3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
mydf

#       doc   subj.1            subj.2             subj.3
# 1 blabla1    apple           coconut              berry
# 2 blabla2    prune             apple             banana
# 3 blabla3  coconut            cherry    apple and berry
# 4 blabla4    berry  banana and prune               pear
```

the output for subject "apple" should look like this:

```
#       doc   subj.1            subj.2             subj.3
# 1 blabla1    apple           coconut              berry
# 2 blabla2    prune             apple             banana
# 3 blabla3  coconut            cherry    apple and berry
```

EDIT1:
In addition, let's say i have about 200 different subjects and therefor I want 200 different data.frames. How could I do that?

I tried a loop approach:

```
mylist <- vector('list', length(subjects))

for(i in 1:length(subjects)) {
pattern <- subjects[i]
filter <- grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.1)
      grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.2)
      grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.3)
    subDF <- panel[filter,] 

mylist[[i]] <- subDF
  }
```

but there's the error:

```
Error in grepl(pattern, ignore.case = T, panel$SUBJECT.1) : 
 invalid regular expression 'C++ PROGRAMMING', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

EDIT2: oh I see, in the original data.frame, one of the subjects is "C++ PROGRAMMING". Might that "++" cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`grepl`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) function :

```
pattern <- 'apple'
filter <- grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.1) | 
          grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.2) | 
          grepl(pattern, ignore.case=T, mydf$subj.3)
subDF <- mydf[filter,] 

> subDF 
      doc  subj.1  subj.2          subj.3
1 blabla1   apple coconut           berry
2 blabla2   prune   apple          banana
3 blabla3 coconut  cherry apple and berry
```

**EDIT :**

About your question on for-loop, I don't see any problem in using it, and I doubt using a apply-family function would give many benefits in term of execution time.

For the error, the problem is that the string pattern passed to `grepl` has to be a valid regular expression but `'+'` is a special character and so `'++'` is not allowed.
Anyway, if you just want to check if the subject string is contained in the column, you can disable the regular expression engine by setting the `grepl` argument `fixed=TRUE` (
this means pattern is a string to be matched as is).

The only drawback is that `ignore.case` cannot be used with `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: Here's another way to make that `filter` variable if you have a lot of columns: `filter<-apply(sapply(mydf[,2:4], grepl, pattern="apple", ignore.case=T), 1, any)` -- just change `2:4` to whatever columns you want to search

Comment: @MrFlick, I was thinking more along `unique(unlist(lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) which(grepl("apple", x)))))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Good suggestion. That appears to be more efficient in my benchmark tests http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=mGlxBYaJ&version=1

Comment: @MrFlick, it avoids the dual `*apply`s, and `lapply` *should* always be faster than `sapply`. Thanks for benchmarking! :-)

Comment: @All: thank you for your answers! I edited the question, because I'm trying a loop approach to speed up the process in a big data.frame. Has anyone got an idea how to do that properly?